# Should I use separate JS files for each HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm building a webpage and going to put multiple canvases on it. Should I create a separate JS file for each canvas or should it all go into one file? My biggest concern is coordinating my functions that I want to utilize on all canvases with each individual canvas element and context.

Thanks very much

Comment: modularize your code using any AMD libs like requirejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends.

You shouldn't have separate files *because* they're dealing with different canvases. You should use a different file only when it makes it more readable to do so, or there are certain things that you're going to reuse in various scripts and don't want to download the whole script.

If it makes it more readable for you to have different files for different canvases **because** you're separating concerns that are **not** necessarily related to the canvases, but in this case are, or because there's a file that deals with a specific canvas that will be on multiple pages, so you can reuse the file, then sure.

But there's no point in having a different file just because it's dealing with a different canvas.

Answer (score -1):

I would add every canvas in separate file, because it would allow you to control and change them more easily
Then you can store their urls in an array, loop through it and call each file
You can try the following, if you're using jQuery:

```
var urls = [/*urls*/];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
    /* Get file */
}
```

Let me know if this suits your needs